# Where can I recycle #81 composite materials?

Tags: recycling, usa

I noticed my pet food bag has a recycling symbol with a new number in it - #81:

[image: Package with #81 recycling symbol]

The only resource I've found about this symbol is the [Wikipedia page on recycling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_codes), which describes it as Paper/Plastic composite material.

Can this material be recycled anywhere in the USA? Is there any more information about this (new?) recycling category?

Comment: Recycling plastic-coated paper is hard because you'll need to separate the plastic from the paper. That's why most recycling programs don't accept it.

Comment: I don't know much about recycling programs in the US, but according to [this presentation](http://ecocycle.org/files/pdfs/microplastics_in_compost_presentation.pdf) many US compost collection programs accept plastic-coated paper products, strangely enough!?. I'm not sure how they solve the problem of microplastics ending up in the compost (they probably don't!), so I think it would be best to either throw it in the general waste for now, or along with other plastics (if you have such a recycling scheme). Alternatively, you can also ask your local waste management facility for advice.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_codes) on Wikipedia, #81 is **paper and plastic composite**.

When it comes to recycling, you have two options:

1. Go to the website of your county or city recycling agency to see if they will accept this material. If they don't, you could try neighboring counties/cities (areas with larger populations will tend to have broader recycling programs). For the US, I was not able to find any comprehensive listing of recycling policies and/or agencies.
2. Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5be3pqh07KI) for instructions on how to separate the paper and plastic layers - typically the interior paper layer (which is in contact with the food) would be soiled and thus non-recyclable, while the outer plastic layer could be recycled with other similar plastics.

Answer (score 2):

Try Terracycle, look on their website as they recycle hard to recycle items and have a mixture of paid for and free schemes.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Please be aware that we require all answerers to state their affiliation to recommended products and services. Are you affiliated with Terracycle?