# How to dispose of coated paper take-out container

Tags: recycling, paper

I have a paper-based take-out container from a restaurant take-home meal:

[image: bottom of container]

The inside is lined with some waterproof coating. I can't tell if it is wax or plastic.

"Please recycle this container", it says.  Would it be OK to recycle it as paper along with the usual curbside recycling? Or should I treat it like a Tetra Pak container?  Or maybe I could toss it in the city compost?

(Location is Vancouver, Canada, if it makes a difference.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I recycle #81 composite materials?](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2945/99), but sadly so far there are no good answers on that question. It probably depends on whether it is wax or plastic. Perhaps the restaurant in question, or your local recycling center has the answer?

Comment: Definitely a good question for the restaurant. If they are true proponents of recycling, they will know where and how.

Answer (score 4):

Since the original poster is in Vancouver, British Columbia, here is a response to this same question from the Recycling Council of British Columbia (Hotline@rcbc.ca)

Summary:  Rinse and remove grease soaked portions (garbage) before placing in the Blue Bin.

> That container you have is a tricky item to deal with.  Since it is product packaging, it is accepted in the blue bin under the Recycle BC program in the category of cartons and paper cups (please refer to the information here:  https://recyclebc.ca/what-can-i-recycle/#1489681710401-fac7cf1f-7218).  Sounds like the grease hasn’t contaminated most of the paper in this container, so we think that it would still be worth recycling in order for the paper content to not be wasted.  It can’t be put in the organics stream due to the plastic (for explanation, see video here:  https://www.rcbc.ca/resources/faqs/composting3).  Just be sure to clean this item as you would for other recyclables before putting it with your curbside recycling.  If you think that the item is too soiled due to the grease, then it should be placed in the garbage, unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no such thing as #8, #81 composite paper/plastic can only be recycled by separating the plastic from the paper, and in the U.S., many recycling companies accept this material, but I was unable to find out the method that they use, if they even use one. However, Canada may have different regulations, and I would doubt that the material is accepted for recycling.

Look here for the different materials:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_codes

Comment: I've seen different reports of what resin code nr 8 means; [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_codes) says #8 means lead-acid battery. On [this forum](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=605819) it has been suggested that some manufacturers may just use it improperly, or that #8 is a general recycling symbol. However, the latter seems incorrect and is probably a misinterpretation of [this site](https://signsanddisplays.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/universal-plastic-recycling-symbols/) where the 8th logo happens to be a general recycling logo without a number.

Comment: BTW, the picture supplied by the OP does say #8

Comment: According to wikipedia's list and Canada's list of recycling identifiers, there is no #8.

Comment: The wikipedia link in your post clearly mentions "#8 Lead - Lead–acid battery".